# WebDriverException : Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm trying to open a browser and login. In using Robot, Robot Ride and Robot-selenium.

But, Chrome opens and closes abruptly.

```
Python : 3.5.1
Robot framework : 3.1.2
Ride : 1.7.4
Chrome : 79.0.3945.88
OS : Windows 10.
selenium2library : 3.0.0
```

I've downloaded the corresponding version of chrome driver and kept in Python\Scripts

My Test Case:

```
${b_id}    Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
Input text    ${loginIDLocator}    ${u_name}
Input text    ${pswdLocator}    ${password}
```

The username can be given, but the chrome closes abruptly before the password is entered.

There is an exception :
*WebDriverException : Message: chrome not reachable*

The same code with same versions of Robot,Ride and Selenium works on other system.

Please let me know where I'm wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you expand the example test case including all sections?

Comment: I'm trying to open  page with Google.com as URL even that wasnt working. However, I got the OS reinstalled. And it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Selenium2Library and then install robotframework-seleniumlibrary. Edit test cases to use SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and the result is the same. In the Test Case, I've explicitly mentioned, SeleniumLibrary.<keyword>.  Also, I observe that, the execution stops abruptly when the "Capture Page Screenshot" is called. This behaviour is same with both Selenium2Library and SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: Create a basic test to see if there are problems with `Capture Page Screenshot`:
```
Set Log Level    TRACE
Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Chrome
Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this option too. And I got my OS reinstalled and it works fine now with the same set of commands that I had  used previously...